SQLAlchemy ORM Enabled Update
I am trying to use SQLAchemy's update statement to update a reflected table in PostgreSQL.
If I create a table in PostgreSQL like this:
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    test_id int NOT NULL,
    test_name varchar(10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(test_id)
)

Then I go back to Python, create a Metadata object and reflect the database to the Metadata object thus:
postgres_metadata_obj = MetaData()
postgres_metadata_obj.reflect(bind=postgres_server_engine)

Then get the table from the Metadata object.
test_table = postgres_metadata_obj.tables['test_table']

Insert some data:
data = [{'test_id': 1, 'test_name': 'comes'},
 {'test_id': 2, 'test_name': 'with'},
 {'test_id': 3, 'test_name': 'two'},
 {'test_id': 4, 'test_name': 'APIs,'},
 {'test_id': 5, 'test_name': 'the'},
 {'test_id': 6, 'test_name': 'native'},
 {'test_id': 7, 'test_name': 'pg8000'},
 {'test_id': 8, 'test_name': 'API'},
 {'test_id': 9, 'test_name': 'and'}]

with Session(postgres_server_engine) as postgres_session:
    postgres_session.execute(insert(test_table),data)
    postgres_session.commit()

Now I want to update the data which should be fairly straightforward.
updates = [{"test_id": 8, "test_name": "upAPI"},{"test_id": 9, "test_name": "upand"}]

with Session(postgres_server_engine) as postgres_session:
    postgres_session.execute(update(test_table),updates)
    postgres_session.commit()

But it throws a UniqueViolation Error because of the primary key. The generated SQL is wrong.
DETAIL:  Key (test_id)=(8) already exists.

[SQL: UPDATE test_table SET test_id=%(test_id)s, test_name=%(test_name)s]
[parameters: [{'test_id': 8, 'test_name': 'upAPI'}, {'test_id': 9, 'test_name': 'upand'}]]

The documentation (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-queryguide-bulk-update) says the following:
Passing the Update construct along with a list of parameter dictionaries which each include a full primary key value will invoke bulk UPDATE by primary key mode for the statement, generating the appropriate WHERE criteria to match each row by primary key, and using executemany to run each parameter set against the UPDATE statement:
What am I doing wrong?
PostgreSQL 16
SQLAlchemy '2.0.30'
Python 3.12.3

The documentation you cited is for ORM, but test_table is not an ORM object, it is a (Core) Table object. Look here for instructions on using bindparam() to do multi-row updates in Core.

Thanks. Created an ORM object using reflection and it works
